# Pandas groupby sales item and count sales per month in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Hi I have a pandas dataframe that looks roughly like this:

| Date | Item | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | iphone | $20 |
| 02-01-2022 | iphone | $40 |
| 01-02-2022 | iphone | $40 |
| 02-02-2022 | macbook | $20 |
| 03-02-2022 | macbook | $40 |
| 04-02-2022 | macbook | $50 |

I am trying to get the count per item per month in a format like this:

| Item | January | February |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iphone | 2 | 1 |
| macbook | 0 | 3 |

and in the end I want a column that takes the average of each column. So the final dataframe would look like:

| Item | January | February | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iphone | 2 | 1 | 1,5 |
| macbook | 0 | 3 | 1,5 |

I have tried many pandas groupby functions but I can't seem to get it done. Can somebody help me?

I tried to use pd.Grouper(freq='M') but that didn't work out so well. The months don't show up as columns but as rows per sales item. Any ideas?

Comment: How did u got that avg 1,5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `crosstab`:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['Item'], pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%B'))
   .assign(Average=lambda d: d.mean(axis=1))
)
```

Output:

```
Date     February  January  Average
Item                               
iphone          1        2      1.5
macbook         3        0      1.5
```

Alternative for sorted month names:

```
from calendar import month_name

(pd.crosstab(df['Item'], pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.month)
   .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(month_name)))
   .assign(Average=lambda d: d.mean(axis=1))
)
```

Output:

```
Date     January  February  Average
Item                               
iphone         2         1      1.5
macbook        0         3      1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
            Item    Sales
Date        
2022-01-01  iphone  $20
2022-02-01  iphone  $40
2022-01-02  iphone  $40
2022-02-02  macbook $20
2022-03-02  macbook $40
2022-04-02  macbook $50
```

when `date` column is `DatetimeIndex`, aggregate by month and make `df1`

```
df1 = (df
       .groupby([df.index.to_period(freq='M'), 'Item'])['Sales'].count()
       .unstack(level=0)
       .fillna(0))
```

output(df1):

```
Date    2022-01 2022-02 2022-03 2022-04
Item                
iphone  2.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
macbook 0.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
```

and make columns to local name and make `Average` column

```
(df1
 .set_axis(df1.columns.strftime('%B'), axis=1)
 .assign(Average=lambda x: x.mean(axis=1)))
```

output:

```
Date    January February    March   April   Average
Item                    
iphone  2.0     1.0         0.0     0.0     0.75
macbook 0.0     1.0         1.0     1.0     0.75
```